# Mongoose Query most recent doc w/ a bool value set to false

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to write a query that chooses the most recently created entry that also has a false value.
My schema looks like this:

```
var EntrySchema = new Schema({
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    booth: Number,
    used: Boolean,
    strip: String,
    intro: String,
    sess1: String,
    sess2: String,
    sess3: String,
    sess4: String
});
```

I'm looking to only return ONE entry that has a 'used' key set to false. Any help would be appreciated!

This is what i'm working with now.

`Entry.find({used: false}).sort({timestamp:-1}).limit(1).exec(
      function (err, entrys) {
          if (err) {
              return handleError(res, err);
          }
          return res.json(200, entrys);
      }
  );`

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward; can you edit your question to show what you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  That looks correct to me; what's not working about it?

Comment: You know what I think it is working... HHAA

Comment: :) Probably best to just delete the question then.